# While implementing xmpp chat in ios app, it did not recieve message from other end while message sent succesfully?

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I have implemented xmpp chat in ios app, connection get established, get authenticated, message successfully sent but it not recieving message from other end??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send a presence stanza, either without a priority subelement (which means priority 0), or with a priority element that is 0 or higher, in order to receive messages:

```
<presence>
  <priority>10</priority>
</presence>
```